# Curl: (51) error when trying to check whether or not my website redirects correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, curl, https

When I try to make up a `.htaccess` file to redirect my www to non-www, I get some issues.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is the `.htaccess` file I've used, after using: `curl -I https://www` I get:

> curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

But after using `curl -I http://www` I get a 301 redirection, which was my intended case but it redirects to HTTPS www.

The problem of that is that I get a DNS error when I'm visiting it on the internet.

How can I possibly fix this?

Comment: Did you implement HSTS?

Comment: I did indeed do that.

Answer (score 8):

Your ssl certificate is propably self-signed, try using curl with the `-k` (`--insecure`) option which disables ssl verification.

Comment: That seems to give me the right info, but how can I then counter the NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID from Chrome?